# get full category structure by post id

Tags: categories

I have three level category structure as bellow.

```
- parent 1
  - parent sub 1
    - child 1
    - child 2
  - parent sub 2
    - child 3
    - child 4
```

Unfortunately, some of posts doesn't fill correctly which means it ticks only the sub parent level or child level.

I have a specific requirement to get whole category structure by post id. So I used following code to retrieve the ids,

```
wp_get_post_categories( $post_id )
```

This is only giving me the category ids which was ticked, but I need the full category structure.

Eg :

if a posts ticked only `child 2`, from above code I get only `child 2` cat id. instead of that I need `child 2`,`parent sub 1` & `parent 1` cat ids.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [get_ancestors](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)?

Ideally, you would do this in a hook after the post has been updated and add the parent categories to the post so that you can use them in Queries.